# C# how to move section of code to call from different events

Tags: c#

Just to preface. I'm very new to c#.

So I have a windows form with both a `TextBox` and `RichTextBox`. I want them to do basically the same thing but the `RichTextBox` to be able to loop what's written. I've already coded for when the enter key is pressed in the `TextBox` but don't want to have to write basically all the same code for the `RichTextBox`. So basically what I'm asking is, how would I put this code into a separate class or just somewhere else and just call it on either a button press or key press to run from both the text input boxes and be able to loop it for the `RichTextBox`? The code I've included is for when the Enter key is pressed in the `TextBox`.

I have tried searching for a solution but I think I'm struggling with wording it properly.

```cs
private void commandline_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string Command = commandline.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    string[] Commandsplit = Command.Split(' ', ',');
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("ENTER PRESSED");

        if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("moveto") == true || Commandsplit[0].Equals("move") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.xPos = positionx;
            Canvas.yPos = positiony;

        }

        else if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("drawto") == true || Commandsplit[0].Equals("draw") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.toX = positionx;
            Canvas.toY = positiony;
            MyCanvas.DrawLine(Canvas.toX, Canvas.toY);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - LINE DRAWN");

        }

        else if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("square") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[1], out positionshape)) ; //translate string to int
            
            Canvas.sizes = positionshape;
            MyCanvas.DrawSquare(Canvas.sizes);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - SQUARE DRAWN");


        }
        else if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("rectangle") == true || Commandsplit[0].Equals("rect") == true) //what happens if draw rectangle command is used
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[2], out positiony)) ;

            Canvas.sizerx = positionx;
            Canvas.sizery = positiony;
            MyCanvas.DrawRect(Canvas.sizerx, Canvas.sizery);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW RECTANGLE");
        }
        else if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("circle") == true)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandsplit[1], out positionx)) ;

            Canvas.sizec = positionx;
            MyCanvas.DrawCircle(Canvas.sizec);
            Refresh();//refresh display
            Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW CIRCLE");
        }
        else if (Commandsplit[0].Equals("colour") == true || Commandsplit[0].Equals("col") == true || Commandsplit[0].Equals("color") == true) //changes colour of the pen
        {
            if (Commandsplit[1].Equals("red") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("r") == true)
            {
                Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else if (Commandsplit[1].Equals("blue") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("bl") == true)
            {
                Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (Commandsplit[1].Equals("black") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("blk") == true)
            {
                Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            }
            else if (Commandsplit[1].Equals("green") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("g") == true)
            {
                Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else if (Commandsplit[1].Equals("yellow") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("yel") == true || Commandsplit[1].Equals("y") == true)
            {
                Canvas.P1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }


        }

        commandline.Text = ""; //clears text from command line
        Console.WriteLine("CONSOLE CLEARED");
        Refresh();//refresh display
    }
}
```

Comment: Markdown note: triple-backticks are used for code *blocks*. For inline code, you just need a single backtick at the start and end.

Comment: What does it mean to "loop it for the RichTextBox" exactly?

Comment: You can use the `sender` parameter and check wether it is a `TextBox` or a `RichTextBox` so you adjust your code

Comment: I need it to loop so it runs for multiple line inputted into the `RichTextBox` rather than just the one in the `TextBox`

Comment: Okay, so this now sounds like two different questions: one about code reuse, and one about extracting multiple lines from a `RichTextBox`. I would suggest those would be best tackled separately.

Comment: As a side note, I'd strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, e.g. starting local variable names with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the event handler for most of the controls use the same signature for `KeyDown` events

```
private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { // some code // }
```

so you could attach the same event handler to both elements

```
myTextBox.KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
myRichtextBox.KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
```

Furthermore, you could just make your functionality a standard method and call it from both (separate) handlers

```
function DoMyThing(){ // your existing code here // }

myTextBox.KeyDown += (sender,e) => { DoMyThing(); }
myRichTextBox.KeyDown += (sender,e) => { 
  for(i=0;i<something;i++) // not sure what you wanted to loop!
  {
      DoMyThing(); 
  }
}
```